# Gerar Log por data do dia C#

Tags: c#

Tenho esse código abaixo, teria como gerar Log pela data do dia? *Exemplo*: `log_29072020.txt`

```
private void Log(string mensagem)
{   
    string ficheiro = Environment
        .GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer) 
            + @"\Debug\Log.txt";
   
    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(ficheiro)))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(ficheiro));

    StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(ficheiro, true, Encoding.Default);
    file.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " > " + mensagem);
    file.Dispose();
}
```

E criar uma ação do que foi feito do sistema, apenas tenho a mensagem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente no nome do arquivo coloque da seguinte forma:

```
@"\Debug\log" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + ".txt"
```

que a formatação especificada na sua pergunta. Exemplo final:

```
private void Log(string mensagem)
{   
    string ficheiro = Environment
        .GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer) 
            + @"\Debug\log_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + ".txt";
   
    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(ficheiro)))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(ficheiro));

    StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(ficheiro, true, Encoding.Default);
    file.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " > " + mensagem);
    file.Dispose();
}
```

Estou me atentando ao nome do arquivo, não se o código é a melhor forma de resolver o problema.

Comment: Obrigado Virgilio Novic

Comment: se for a resposta esperada por favor assinale como resposta @EvanilsonSilva

Comment: nesse mesmo código teria como restringir a quantidade de log criado, exemplo: quando chegasse em uma quantidade de 30 logs, no log seguinte ele apagasse ou sobrescrevesse o primeiro log, assim ficando sempre a quantidade de 30 logs, teria como fazer ?

Comment: @EvanilsonSilva sim, programação é ilimitada, só que ai já é outra duvida, cada duvida gera uma pergunta aqui no pt.stackoverflow para melhor organização ... então crie outra pergunta

Comment: Entendo, obrigado mais uma vez @Virgilio Novic

Answer (score 0):

Podes formatar o output com `Datetime.Now.ToString("dd mm yy")` ou algo do género. Caso queiras dar uma vista de olhos na documentação de algum loger como o log4net, [aqui](https://www.google.com/amp/s/stackify.com/log4net-guide-dotnet-logging/amp/) podes encontrar exemplos de como fazer o que pretendes usando essa ferramenta. Além de que evitas ter de implementar o acesso a ficheiros e podes ainda imprimir os logs para vários outputs.